# how to include library header files

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am new to colcon and ros in general, so please forgive my newby question. I completed the all the beginner ROS2 tutorials and all went well.

Now I am trying to compile some third party code into a library (feetech_driver) to use in another ROS package (ft_joint). I have been able to compile the library and the output files are copied to

```
ros_ws/install/feetech_driver
      |-include
      |-lib
      |-share
```

All the header files are in the ros_ws/install/feetech_driver/include/feetech_driver directory

My other ROS package (ft_joint) that is trying to use this library package cannot find the required header file, I am including it like so,

```
#include "feetech_driver/SCSCL.h"
```

As part of my ft_joint package I also include files from the tutorial_interfaces tutorial and I can include those without error, like so,

```
#include "tutorial_interfaces/msg/num.hpp"
```

My CMakeList.txt has a find_package for both packages, like so

```
find_package(tutorial_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(feetech_driver REQUIRED)
```

The error that I get when I run

```
colcon build --packages-select ft_joint
```

is

```
/home/stewart/ros/dev_ws/src/ft_joint/src/joint_node.cpp:6:10: fatal error: feetech_driver/SCSCL.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "feetech_driver/SCSCL.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Stew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364293/how-to-include-library-header-files/) by [stewart menday](https://answers.ros.org/users/61838/stewart-menday/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In this [repo](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/topics/minimal_publisher/) you will find some basic ROS 2 examples. For example you should have a look to this [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/topics/minimal_publisher/CMakeLists.txt).

You should find_package:

```
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
```

And then if it's a ROS 2 dependency, you should link against it

```
ament_target_dependencies(<you target name> rclcpp )
```

If it's not a ROS 2 dependency, then you should use the CMake functions. Like `target_link_libraries` or `target_include_directories`.

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stewart menday](https://answers.ros.org/users/61838/stewart-menday/) on 2020-10-29**:
Thank you for your answer. I have been able to get it to work as follows,
In my CMakeList.txt file I originally had

```
find_package(feetech_driver REQUIRED)

add_executable(joint_node src/joint_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(joint_node rclcpp tutorial_interfaces feetech_driver ft_message)
```

Which didn't work, it wouldn't find the headers or the feetech_driver library file. After changing CMakeList.txt to

```
find_package(feetech_driver REQUIRED)
#don't know why the find_package(feetech_driver REQUIRED) above isn't sufficient, but need the 2 lines below
find_library(DRIVER ftd_scscl)
find_path(HEADERS NAMES SCSCL.h SCSerial.h SCServo.h SCS.h HINTS ${AMENT_PREFIX_PATH})
add_executable(joint_node src/joint_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(joint_node rclcpp tutorial_interfaces feetech_driver ft_message)
target_include_directories(joint_node PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${HEADERS}>)
target_link_libraries(joint_node ${DRIVER})
```

It now works :)